# Run a program several times with diffrent inputs

Tags: c++

Iv written a program with C++ that takes 259 double numbers and then compute some attributes of these numbers. Iv generated my desired input and put it in a file called `input.txt`. This file contains 1000 test cases, That means (1000*259) double numbers in a single text file. How can I run my program 1000 times and give the generated input to it?

Comment: Maybe command line arguments?

Answer (score 3):

If you write a function that processes a single line

```
double Compute(std::vector<double> const& nums)
{
    // do something with nums
    return answer;
}
```

Then you can use this function in a loop. Here is rough psuedocode that shows one method to do this.

```
int main()
{
    // open your file
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        // create a std::vector<double> from line
        double answer = Compute(your_vector);
    }
    return 0;
}
```